# What is the relationship between ssh -T runtime config and /etc/ssh/sshd_config for OpenSSH?

Tags: ssh

I notice that when I run `sshd -T` to get the runtime values of the OpennSSH sshd config it differs from what is in the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file itself.

Im struggling to understand how to manipulate them separately and how they are related. If I change whats in /etc/ssh/sshd_config, how do I then reflect those changes in the output of sshd -T?

Answer (score 1):

The OpenSSH sshd allows an administrator to both set configuration settings in a configuration file ([`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config) by default) and on the start up command line with [`sshd -oOPTION1=value -oOPTION2=value`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sshd).

RHEL 9 and derivatives use the command line option construction to adjust crypto settings, to enforce the systemwide crypto policy for `sshd` and effectively ignore whatever crypto settings get configured in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

See for background https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/9/html/security_hardening/using-the-system-wide-cryptographic-policies_security-hardening

Only once you opt-out `sshd` from the systemwide crypto policy ( by editing `/etc/sysconfig/sshd` and uncommenting the line `# CRYPTO_POLICY=` ) will the effective sshd configuration be solely determined by the contents of `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

That might explain your observations.

Answer (score 1):

When you run sshd -T, it reads the configuration from /etc/ssh/sshd_config and prints out the effective configuration that would be used if the server were started with those settings

It could be that there is also config in /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*, which results in seeing a different configuration. (the configs in there are included in the sshd_config `Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf`)

You could do `grep -E -h -v '^#|^\s*$' /etc/ssh/sshd_config /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf` to check both